# Sizer.Remove(): arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: python, wxpython

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix the following error:

`self.vbSizers[turnNum].Remove(self.locations[turnNum])`

builtins.TypeError: Sizer.Remove(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'TextPanel'
overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'TextPanel'

The "ADD" command works:

`self.vbSizers[turnNum].Add(self.locations[turnNum], 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTRE)`

Then why does the "Remove" command not work? Here is the link to the source code:

https://github.com/horald/londonlaw/blob/master/londonlaw/guiclient/HistoryWindow.py
at line 104

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it to the question. Also make sure to read [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The "ADD" command works:

<code>
self.vbSizers[turnNum].Add(self.locations[turnNum], 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTRE)
</code>

Then why does the "Remove" command not work? Here is the link to the source code:

https://github.com/horald/londonlaw/blob/master/londonlaw/guiclient/HistoryWindow.py
at line 104

Answer (score 0):

The `Remove` function on a BoxSizer expects an index as input.

```
Remove(...)
    Remove(sizer) -> bool
    Remove(index) -> bool
    
    Removes a sizer child from the sizer and destroys it.
```